# Change "welcome" message and add "Login as another user" link

Tags: authentication, magento-1.7

I would like to change the "welcome" message in Magento 1.7 to display another message saying:

```
Welcome <User>
Not <User>? Login as another user
```

The above message is displayed when the user is logged in. Here `Login` is a link.

When the user clicks on `Login`, it should first Logout the current session User and then redirect to the Login page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the welcome message in header.phtml file.
(the path is : app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/page/html)

For the **login** link, give customer/account/logout in href.

To redirect the page after logout, copy the core file

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

to local folder

app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php 
and change redirection in logoutAction() method.